# Window contentOrientation M1 error

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a QML Window which I want to assign `contentOrientation` property to `Qt::LandscapeOrientation` resulting in following line of code:

```
contentOrientation: "Qt::LandscapeOrientation"
```

Qt Creator shows me the following error in this code:

> Invalid value for enum. (M1)

I am aware this is a very dumb error (I expect some downgrades :D), but how do I solve it?

Comment: Don't forget, it's Javascript, not C++, I guess you need `Qt.LandscapeOrientation`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In QML, the enums from the C++ Qt namespace area [available in the `Qt.X` form](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#enums):

```
contentOrientation: Qt.LandscapeOrientation
```

The [documentation could be clearer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#contentOrientation-prop) about this, as it still says:

> The default value is Qt::PrimaryOrientation.

I imagine that this is because the values are not documented in QML to avoid duplication, and this is the only way that they can be linked to.